# Insert Data Into Column

Tags: mysql, insert

Alright, I have a column named id which has 2000 "ids" in them, and I have a newly added field called "name".

I was wondering how would I go about inserting a list of names so they line up to their corresponding id?

## id || name

```
1 || bob
2 || smith
3 || john
4 || louis
5 || kevin
6 || jacob
7 || tim
```

My apologies for not being to clear with the question. id and name are both in the same table "cards". The cards were added in the past with other bits of data like descriptions, colors, etc so there are already quite a lot of id's that have been generated. I was just asked to add a name field to the table "cards" and insert data from a spread sheet into said name field.

Comment: The question isn't very clear...

Comment: Where does the list of names reside, and does it have the IDs as well?

Comment: My apologies for not being to clear with the question. id and name are both in the same table "cards". The cards were added in the past with other bits of data like descriptions, colors, etc so there are already quite a lot of id's that have been generated. I was just asked to add a name field to the table "cards" and insert data from a spread sheet into said name field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've got the data in a spreadsheet, with 2 columns, id and name, you could do the following:

In the 3rd column of the spreadsheet, do

```
=CONCATENATE("UPDATE cards SET name = '",A1,"' WHERE id = ",A2,";")
```

then drag that formula down all rows. You can then just run the queries generated. For 2000 rows, it shouldn't take long.

Comment: Assuming you're using Excel. If not, different functions would work too in the same way.

Comment: @gmadd, Yeah, the data I will be given is in an excel spreadsheet and I just need to add that data to the table. Thus far the table only contains the "id", and the spreadsheet has "name"

Comment: @gmadd, Thanks for the suggestion. It exactly what I needed to get the job done.

Comment: @gmadd or anybody else, Quick question,my query is UPDATE cards SET meta_description = 'Amy's bugs address labels are printed on recycled label paper. Available in quantities of 30. Each label is 2.5 x 1 inch with rounded corners.' WHERE card_id = 'al007'; .. If you look at it the " ' " in Amy's is throwing off the query, how do I get around this using @gmadd's method in excel

Comment: you could use a replace method, although if it's for 2000 records, I'd probably just search for apostrophes and manually escape them with \' before running the queries

Comment: Thanks @gmadd. I did just end up using a "find all and replace" where I inserted "\" to escape it. Thanks for the help. You saved me a lot of time and headache.

Answer (score 2):

You need a known relationship between id and name.  So your name list must contain the id's before you use it to update your table.  Since this must be the case, create a temporary table with id, name and use it to update the main table.  e.g.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable(id INT(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY, 
                                firstname VARCHAR(20));
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/mynames.txt' INTO tmptable(id, firstname);
UPDATE mytable m JOIN tmptable t ON (m.id=t.id) SET m.firstname=t.firstname;
```

Check out `LOAD DATA INFILE` syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).